# Observer for MutableLiveData not being triggered

Tags: java, android, mvvm, mutablelivedata

I am developing an activity using MutableLiveData to keep my fragments up-to-date with the results retrieved from a search, but the Observer is not being triggered after the list of results is updated.

I have, on the main activity, an EditText where I type what I want to search and, right below it, a ViewPager widget with three options, to where the results are subdivided into three categories (on three different fragments). When I first enter the activity, I run an initial search to retrieve data and populate the three fragments. This works perfectly.

**SearchActivity.java**

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);

        /* Init TabMenu */
        TabLayout tabSearchMenu = findViewById(R.id.tabSearchMenu);
        ViewPager vpSearch = findViewById(R.id.vpSearchResult);

        TabSearchPageAdapter tabSearchPageAdapter = new TabSearchPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabSearchMenu.getTabCount());
        vpSearch.setAdapter(tabSearchPageAdapter);
        vpSearch.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabSearchMenu));


        /* Init Search */
        etxtSearch = findViewById(R.id.etxtSearch);
        etxtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, actionId, keyEvent) -> {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                mViewModel.searchText(etxtSearch.getText().toString());
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
```

**SearchViewModel.java**

```java
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<ProductItemModel>> listProducts = new MutableLiveData<>(new ArrayList<>());
    private List<ProductItemModel> mProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    [...]

    public void searchText(String text) {
        // make search... 
        // ...
        // ...

        // Process Json result.
        CompletionHandler completionHandler = (content, error) -> {
            if (content != null && content.length() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, content.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "searchText: found result.");

                listProducts = new MutableLiveData<>(new ArrayList<>());

                mProducts = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    JSONArray products = content.getJSONArray("hits");

                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject prodObject = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        ProductItemModel prodItem = new ProductItemModel(prodObject);

                        mProducts.add(prodItem);

                        Log.d(TAG, "searchText: " + prodObject.toString());
                    }

                    listProducts.setValue(mProducts);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "searchText: no hits");
            }
        };
    }

    [...]

    MutableLiveData<List<ProductItemModel>> getProductList() {
        if (listProducts == null)
            return new MutableLiveData<>(new ArrayList<>());

        return listProducts;
    }
}
```

**SearchProductFragment**

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        InitFragment();
    }

    [...]

    private void InitFragment() {
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(SearchViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.SearchProducts();

        final Observer<List<ProductItemModel>> listObserver = result -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "listObserver: observer modified.");
            if (result.size() > 0) {
                InitProductList(result);
            }
        };

        mViewModel.getProductList().observe(getActivity(), listObserver);
    }
```

Already tried to move the method `InitFragment()` inside the fragment to the `OnActivityCreated`, but it didn't worked either.
I know for a fact that what is not working is the observer not being triggered. I've made tests with breakpoints.

As you guys can see, when the fragment is initialized the method `SearchProducts()` is called and the result is sent perfectly to the MutableLiveData and the observer is triggered. But whenever I run a search calling the function `searchText()`, retrieve the results from it, and update the value of my variable (works perfect till this point), the observer is not triggered.

Extra info:

- I tried making the search on and off the fragment being active on the
  ViewPager. Both didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rO4r-JOQtA) from the Android team talks about the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're returning different instances of `MutableLiveData`, but your fragment is only observing the first instance that it gets in your `InitFragment()` method.

You're also setting `listProducts` to multiple instances of `MutableLiveData` (first at its declaration site and again in the `searchText()` method) rather than just updating the value that it holds.

To elaborate, you don't need the null check in the `getProductsList()` method because `listProducts` is initialized to a new instance of `MutableLiveData` when the view model is created.

Now, the value held by that instance of `MutableLiveData` might be null.. and it is only that value which you should be updating via `setValue()`. Any null checks on the value of the `MutableLiveData` could be done in the `Observer` you created in your fragment.